# Magento Custom Options showing price in cart/checkout page

Tags: magento

Im trying to show each price for custom option in cart-page and checkout-page.

so I have changed this file: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Configuration.php
here at line 75

```
 $options[] = array(
                    'label' => $option->getTitle(),
                    'value' => $group->getFormattedOptionValue($itemOption->getValue()),
                    'print_value' => $group->getPrintableOptionValue($itemOption->getValue()),
                    'option_id' => $option->getId(),
                    'option_type' => $option->getType(),
                    'custom_view' => $group->isCustomizedView(),

                    //##my changing
                   'my_price' => $option->getPrice()
                );
```

but this works only with fields, not works when my custom option was a select-box or  in radio-buttons.

can someone help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open up your template file

**app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml**

Find the foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
```

Within that foreach loop, add this code:

```
<?php

        $optionId = $_option['option_id'];
        $product = $_item->getProduct();
        $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId);
        $itemOption = $_item->getOptionByCode('option_' . $option->getId());
        $price = false;
        foreach ($option->getValues() as $values) {
            if ($values->getId() == $itemOption['value']) {
                $price = $values->price;
            }
        }
        if ($price !== false) {
            echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($price);
        }

?>
```

Comment: Its not working in magento 1.9.3.2. Display error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object ".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've solved your problem yet, but for reference here's what I did..

The custom option prices are only available from the product object, not from the item object (which is what's readily available from the cart/item/default.phtml template). You'll have to find the product id from the item ($_item->getProductId()) then load this product. From there you'll want to load the product options, iterate through the custom option select values (in my case) and pull out the price when the option value ids match from the product and item objects ( http://subesh.com.np/2009/12/custom-options-product-magento/ for more help ).

Hope this helps you get on your way :)